# How to hook in after user's registration email has been sent?

Tags: hooks, user-registration

I want to redirect to a page **after the user's registration email has been sent**. 
What is the correct hook?

`user_register` is too early, that is the user is entered into the database but the email isn't send.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `registration_redirect` filter. This allows you to set *where* the user is sent to, but leaves WordPress to perform the redirect (after everything has successfully processed).

```
function wpse_139267_registration_redirect( $url ) {
    return site_url( 'thank-you' );
}

add_filter( 'registration_redirect', 'wpse_139267_registration_redirect' );
```

Comment: thanks! This works fine for most cases - still, my problem seems to be a bit more intertwined, so I opened a new case: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/139278/redirect-after-successful-registration-with-fronted-registration-form