# Redirect after successful registration with fronted registration form

Tags: front-end, user-registration, wp-redirect

I am trying to redirect users after failed and successful registrations and logins.
Everything works fine, except the redirection after a successful registration.

Right now, I get redirected to `http://mysite.com/register/?login=failed.` I can't figure out why I am not redirected to `http://mysite/com/login/?redirect_to=mysite.com/change-password` which I specified at the bottom using  `add_action('registration_redirect','redirect_after_success_registration');`

Here's my code:

```
// hook failed login
add_action('wp_login_failed', 'my_frontend_login_fail'); 

function my_frontend_login_fail($username){
    // Get the reffering page, where did the post submission come from?
    $referrer = add_query_arg('login', false, $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

    // if there's a valid referrer, and it's not the default log-in screen
    if(!empty($referrer) && !strstr($referrer,'wp-login') && !strstr($referrer,'wp-admin')){
        // let's append some information (login=failed) to the URL for the theme to use
        wp_redirect( add_query_arg('login', 'failed', $referrer) );         
    //wp_redirect($referrer . '?login=failed'); 
    exit;
    }
}

//hook empty login submit
add_action( 'login_head', 'my_frontend_login_no_pass_no_username' );

function my_frontend_login_no_pass_no_username(){
    $referrer = add_query_arg('login', false, $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    if ( (!isset($_REQUEST['user_login']) || ( isset( $_REQUEST['user_login'] ) && trim( $_REQUEST['user_login'] ) == '' ) ) || (!isset($_REQUEST['user_pass']) || ( isset( $_REQUEST['user_pass'] ) && trim( $_REQUEST['user_pass'] ) == '' ) ) ){
        wp_redirect( add_query_arg('login', 'failed', $referrer) ); 
        exit; 
    }   
}


// unsuccessfull registration
add_action('register_post', 'binda_register_fail_redirect', 99, 3);

function binda_register_fail_redirect( $sanitized_user_login, $user_email, $errors ){
    //this line is copied from register_new_user function of wp-login.php
    $errors = apply_filters( 'registration_errors', $errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email );
    //this if check is copied from register_new_user function of wp-login.php
    if ( $errors->get_error_code() ){
        //setup your custom URL for redirection
        $redirect_url = get_bloginfo('url') . '/register';
        //add error codes to custom redirection URL one by one
        foreach ( $errors->errors as $e => $m ){
            $redirect_url = add_query_arg( $e, '1', $redirect_url );    
        }
        //add finally, redirect to your custom page with all errors in attributes
        wp_redirect( $redirect_url );
        exit;   
    }
}

function redirect_after_success_registration () {
$redirect_url=get_bloginfo('url').'/login/?redirect_to='.get_bloginfo('url').'/change-password';
return $redirect_url;
}
add_filter('registration_redirect','redirect_after_success_registration');
```

I appreciate your ideas and solutions on this one!
Thank you

Comment: are you sure, you get the error on this line for fail registration?

Answer (score 1):

*registration_redirect* is a filter hook, not an action hook, so your *redirect_after_success_registration* function never actually gets run.

See this example of how to redirect using the filter:

[How to redirect a sucessful registration to a page template?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19692/how-to-redirect-a-sucessful-registration-to-a-page-template)

Comment: I changed my original hook as you proposed (edits are made in original post), but still the same result. I get redirected to ../register/?login=failed